Synapse Serverless - OPTIMIZE doesn't seem to do anything. Am I misunderstanding it?
In Synapse Serverless, I ran OPTIMIZE on a delta table to compact the files / hopefully improve performance.
To start, a million - often tiny, parquet files. My understanding is that's suboptimal for performance

So then run an OPTIMIZE command on that table.

Great, it completed. Go back and...

Read performance is unchanged
The files on the datalake appear unchanged as well (identical screenshot - file names, sizes, etc. Granted that's only a subset of the files but...it's still identical, and what are those 7kb files still doing there?)

What am I missing and/or misunderstanding?

The OPTIMIZE command in Synapse Serverless Delta Lake compacts small files into larger ones, which can improve read performance. It appears that after running OPTIMIZE on your delta table, you did not see any change in read performance and the files on the datalake appeared unchanged. One possibility is that the files were already optimized and did not need further optimization. Another possibility is that the OPTIMIZE command did not complete successfully. You can check the logs to see if there were any errors or warnings during the OPTIMIZE operation.

@RakeshGovindula Thanks.  I didn't see any errors. For the 'already optimized' -  there are many 7 kilobyte files - can a large # of 7 kilobyte files be the 'already optimized' state?
